# Automate Sass execution thru terminal (os x) via script

Tags: scripting, command-line, automation, terminal, sass

I started using Haml/Sass thru Rubygems recently, and I'm really liking it (although that doesn't have much to do with my question)...

I would like to create a simple script I can throw in the root directory of each of my projects that will launch terminal, cd to my CSS folder, and run sass. so essentially a script that:

```
cd ~/path_to_here/css/
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compact
```

I'm not really sure the best way to go about this, anything involving the command line is always slightly out of my comfort zone. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This script won't open the Terminal for you; but it will give you a shortcut to do the repetitive task of changing to the project directory and calling the `compass watch` command. (I highly recommend you to use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) which is a SASS compilation of Tools to make your life easier.)

Put this inside your `~/.profile` file and restart your terminal:

```
alias watch=compass_watch_project
function compass_watch_project() {
  cd ~/Dev/ruby/$1;
  compass watch
}
```

Remember to change the `~/Dev/ruby/` to your directory path.

After this you can easily do a `watch myProject`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) for managing the building of your Sass files: It has a script for watching changes in all your project files and setting up all the output parameters.

You can create a simple text file with the extension `.command` which will make it a double-clickable script in OSX:

```
#!/bin/bash
compass watch
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a applescript that would launch terminal, and call a shell script.

Applescript
tell application "Terminal"
do script "pushd /blash/sassstup.sh"
end tell

shell script:
cd cssfolder
/bin/sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compact